# How to make a circle view using percentage in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

How do I make a circle view using percentage in React Native? Use borderRadius don't seem to always work depending on the size of my view.

My View that is supposed to be a circle:

```
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

            <View style={styles.circle}>
                <Icon style={styles.icon} type='FontAwesome' name='phone'/>
            </View>

        </ScrollView>
```

My styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container:{
        flex: 1,
    },
    circle:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: '30%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: '20%',
        borderRadius: 200,
    },
    icon:{
        fontSize: 80,
    },

})
```

Comment: Maybe not the best practice, but you can just use a very large number for borderRadius (eg. 9999), that will always result to a circle.

Comment: @L.Palaiokostas If the icon is not a perfect square, even if i put a very large number for borderRadius it still doesn't turn into a perfect circle, but I can't think in a better way

Comment: It doesn't have to be a perfect square... It works in a non-perfect square as well, as long as it's a square (x*x). If it's not a square, there is no way to turn it into a circle...

Answer (score 0):

Set borderRadius half of the width/height of your view. For Example if you had a view of

> width:10, height:10

then

> borderRadius:5

would work.

Comment: But this way I would be setting the width and height of the container

Answer (score 0):

```
var Circle = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.circle} />
    )
}
})

circle: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100/2,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

for reference [here are more shapes](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native)